# Export import npm global packages

Tags: npm

I would like to reinstall npm from scratch. I wish to reinstall the packages already installed globally *in* npm, after the reinstall. What would be the safest (and non-manual) way to export and import the globally installed modules?

Implementation note: my old npm also required sudo for global installations, so I'm not really looking to reuse the same directory, rather, to have the new npm install the same package list as the old one had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

Will give you the list of the modules (and their versions) you have installed globally. From the output, you'll be able to generate the `npm install` command you'll need (depending on if you wan't to keep the versions / your OS ...)

Comment: Looks good! need to come back here mark it accepted when I complete the process, as it currently hinges on an earlier problem....

Answer (score 22):

#### tl;dr

```sh
# Export
npm list --global --parseable --depth=0 | sed '1d' | awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}' > path/to/npmfile

# Import
xargs npm install --global < path/to/npmfile
```

#### Explanation

Even though the accepted answer gives a pointer, but it does not clearly show how to export/import the global NPM packages.

The output of a simple `npm list` is very hard to parse:

```sh
$ npm list --global --depth=0

/usr/local/lib
├── api-designer@0.1.2
├── bower@1.7.9
├── browserify@13.1.0
├── grunt@1.0.1
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── kong-dashboard@1.1.2
├── npm@3.10.9
├── typescript@2.0.3
├── vue-cli@2.3.1
├── webpack@1.13.2
├── webpack-dev-server@1.16.1
└── yo@1.8.4
```

There are 3 problems with this output:

1. The first line is not a package name
2. Those `└──` are making it hard to parse
3. Versions are not desirable (at least in my case)

Fortunately, NPM devs were thoughtful enough to include a `--parseable` option:

```sh
$ npm list --global --depth=0 --parseable

/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/api-designer
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/kong-dashboard
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
```

Now, the problems are:

1. The first line does not end with a package name as others do
2. Path prefixes before the package name (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`)

If we pipe the output to `sed '1d'`, we get rid of that first line. Then we can drop the path prefixes by piping the output to `awk` to get a clean list of installed package names.

```sh
$ npm list --global --parseable --depth=0 | sed '1d' | awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}'

api-designer
bower
browserify
grunt
gulp
kong-dashboard
npm
typescript
vue-cli
webpack
webpack-dev-server
yo
```

You can simply append a `> /path/to/file` to save the output into the file. Then to install the latest versions of those packages:

```sh
xargs npm install --global < path/to/file
```

You can safely drop the `--global` arg, to import/export the locally installed npm packages.

Comment: If anyone wants the export with version then change the first like to `npm list --global --depth=0 | sed '1d' | awk '{gsub(/[├└]\─*\S/,"",$1); print}' > path/to/npmfile`

Comment: @sepehr : Thanks a million! Finally I could include NPM packages in my constantly evolving backup / restore script and actually understand what I'm doing. Great explanation!

Comment: @SumitKumar @sepehr Hello. I did not get the part of appending the ```> /path/to/file```. How do I do this? I got lost in this part. I will inform a file name that will save the whole list(output) of packages inside? Then I use this same file reference to install the packages into my project?

Comment: @Alioshr You're right. Change `path/to/file` with the real path to the output file. Lookup "Linux I/O redirection".

Comment: @sepehr thanks so much for replying me back here. I thought you guys would take long to check into this old discussion. I am using macOs operational system and I just do not understand how to redirect this path. I am stuck on the part that I see the clean list of installed package names. =D I am still dumb with the terminal. New dev still investing hours in code syntax before exploring more the intrinsic surroundings. Could you kindly elaborate a little so I can understand with a practical example?

Comment: @sepehr would this implicate in me creating a temporary location for the packages?  ```https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/```

Comment: @sepehr I've found this but I still don't understand it quite well =) https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: @Alioshr This works in your macOS terminal as well. Imagine you want to save the list in a file called `mypackages.txt`, the file doesn't exist yet, you don't care it will be created. You should paste this command into your macos terminal: `npm list --global --parseable --depth=0 | sed '1d' | awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}' > mypackages.txt`

Comment: would be good to mention that following expression :
```'{gsub("/.*/","",$1);print}'```
can also be used to get expected value.

Answer (score 2):

I use this on Windows with PowerShell:

`[string]::join(" ", ((npm ls -g --depth=0) | select -skip 1  | select -skiplast 1  | % { $_.remove(0,4) }))`

Answer (score 0):

*Note:*

- *All the scripts below are tested under an environment that does not require `sudo` to install npm packages*
- *The script below always reinstall the latest version*

Here is a bash script to reinstall all npm global packages without exporting to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
list="$(npm list --global --parseable --depth=0 | sed '1d')"
newlist=""
for i in $list; do
  name="${i##*/}"
  newlist+="$name "
done
echo "npm install --global $newlist"
npm install --global $newlist
```

If you want to export global packages to a file and install later:

**export**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# export npm global packages to a backup file
list="$(npm list --global --parseable --depth=0 | sed '1d')"
exportFile="npm_global_pkgs.bkp"
while [ -f "$exportFile" ]; do
  echo "$exportFile exists, try another file name?"
  read exportFile
done
newlist=""
for i in $list; do
  newlist+="${i##*/} "
done
echo "$newlist" > "$exportFile"
echo "Packages exported to "$exportFile":
$newlist"
```

**import**

```
#!/bin/bash
# install npm global packages from a backup file
echo "Enter the importing filename:"
read importFile
list="$(cat "$importFile")"
echo "npm i -g $list"
npm i -g $list
```

In case you are not familiar with how to create and execute a bash script:
Paste each code to a separate file, save it.
you may need to add executable permission:

```
chmod u+x 'filename'
```

then execute the script you want:

```
./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here by the necessity of reinstall a list of packages from a node version X to another node version Y, so based on the previous examples and different views, I achieved this with the following command :

```sh
# get the node modules directory with backslashes included for a correct string replacement
p_replace=$(printf "$(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules\n"|sed -e 's|/|\\/|g')
# apply a string replacement with the previous getting value
npm list -g --parseable --depth 0 | sed '1d' |sed -E "s|$p_replace\/||g" > /tmp/node_packages
```

on my case I got a final output like this :

```sh
$ cat /tmp/node_packages
@vue/cli-service-global
apidoc
browserslist
bufferutil
create-react-app
express-generator
nodemon
npm
serve
utf-8-validate
wscat
```

Finally, I simply executed the following command to reinstall the needed packages :

```sh
xargs -I value npm install -g value < /tmp/node_packages
```

As a part of the packages accuracy, I performed the following validation :

```sh
$ nvm use v11.14.0 &&  npm list -g --depth 0 && \
  nvm use stable &&  npm list -g --depth 0         
          
Now using node v11.14.0 (npm v6.14.10)
/home/mlazo/.nvm/versions/node/v11.14.0/lib
├── @vue/cli-service-global@4.1.1
├── apidoc@0.24.0
├── browserslist@4.12.0
├── bufferutil@4.0.1
├── create-react-app@3.4.1
├── express-generator@4.16.1
├── nodemon@2.0.4
├── npm@6.14.10
├── serve@11.3.2
├── utf-8-validate@5.0.2
└── wscat@4.0.0

Now using node v15.5.0 (npm v6.14.10)
/home/mlazo/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib
├── @vue/cli-service-global@4.5.9
├── apidoc@0.25.0
├── browserslist@4.16.0
├── bufferutil@4.0.3
├── create-react-app@4.0.1
├── express-generator@4.16.1
├── nodemon@2.0.6
├── npm@6.14.10
├── serve@11.3.2
├── utf-8-validate@5.0.4
└── wscat@4.0.1
```

I really hope this would be helpful to anybody that is facing a similar scenario about node version migrations.

Best regards,

Manuel Lazo